# how to sanitize html input using php and whitelisting?

Tags: php, html, sanitization

I have read a lot of questions on this topic but failed to get any satisfactory answers. I have used a WYSIWYG editor named Mooeditable and configured it to allow only:

> <em>Italic</em>, <strong>bold</strong> and <img src = 'images\someuploadedimage.jpg'>image
> No attributes allowed except for src in <img> tag.

I have tried and failed using HTML purify and htmLawed. It was way too complex and overweight for this simple purpose. Can you give me a php function that removes every tag with the inner contents of tag except for bold, italic and simple image tag(with only img tag). Or can you tell me how to configure htmLawed to suit my needs. It seems that it only uses blacklist which would be HUGE in this case.

Comment: Your problem *looks* simple, but it isn't, htmlpurifier and htmLawed are **not** too complex or overweight. Black listing is a terrible approach though, so if htmLawed doesn't support white listing, don't use it.

Comment: Unless you do not specify which other answers you have considered so far and explain why they (and in which part) they were not satisfactory for you, we can and will not answer this non-question. Do not only drop names. And btw, recommendations are off-topic. Keep your question to a concrete programming question please.

Comment: @hakre, almost all of the answer to this question is either to use a strip_tag function which doesnt actually remove the harmful attributes or the readymade html-purify or Htmlaws which is, as far as i know, not suited for this particular case. and the other answers also have flaws. So, Basically what I ask for is a way to just include the above tags and remove all the rest.

And I am new to this Site and thus am unaware of it's rules. So, please just tell me which part of the question did you not uderstand.

Comment: Well, AFAIK you already name the few libraries that can do so. I dunno if HTMLLawed is very well? There is also a bastardized version of KSES  wordpress relies on, but using these older codes, you should really review them. They are probably not as bad as they are called names, but from what I know, most do not take character encoding and HTML well into account. If you can make it more specific (this is a technical matter, e.g. character encoding and HTML/SGML features used), there would be actually some decision points. Checkout as well HTMLTidy that has a node-model as well (very useful).

Comment: Tidy for PHP is here: http://php.net/book.tidy

Comment: Can tidy remove unnecessary tags?? Even if it couldnt, it would be pretty good idea to first tidy the inputted html.
But how exactly do I only keep handful of tags and remove all others??

Comment: Tidy does not sanitise against XSS, it is primarily a code formatter.

Comment: Using Regular Expressions with functions like `preg_replace` is what you need to do.